# Content Showing Undefined when Adding wrong value but not right one

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to add data from a json file to the HTML table below:

Under `(var i = "0";)` I get undefined, but when I change it to `(var i = "dv";)` I get nothing.

Not sure where i'm going wrong and what is causing this issue, i think it's this line `(for (var i = "dv"; i < data.length; i++) {)`

Code is below and json file is : https://pastebin.com/embed_js/rhUz1U5r

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth()
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var dv = ('0' + '/' + month + '/' + day)

    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('spellData.json', function(data) {
            var content;
            for (var i = "dv"; i < data.length; i++) {

                content = $('<tr/>');

                    content.append("<table>");

                    content.append("<tr> <th> Prayer </th> <th> Start </th> <th> Jamaat </th> </tr>");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Fajr: </td> <td> " + data.fajr_begins + " </td> <td> " + data.fajr_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Sunrise: </td> <td> " + data.sunrise + " </td> <td> " + data.sunrise + " </td> </tr> ");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Ishraq: </td> <td> " + data.ishraq + " </td> <td> " + data.ishraq + " </td> </tr> ");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Zuhur: </td> <td> " + data.zuhr_begins + " </td> <td> " + data.zuhr_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Asr: </td> <td> " + data.asr_mithl + " </td>  <td> " + data.asr_jamah + " </td>  </tr> ");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Magrib </td> <td> " + data.maghrib_begins + "</td> <td> " + data.maghrib_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

                    content.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Isha </td> <td> " + data.isha_begins + " </td>  <td> " + data.isha_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

                    content.append("</table>");

                $('table').append(content);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="djpyer"> </div>
    <table></table>
</body>
```

Comment: The data you've provided is not a JSON file. Currently you have an array containing an object which has two keys "11" and "12".

Comment: is this code useless ? the file is from firebase database when exported which is what i used use, The data used to come from firebase but now i been told the data must come locally.

Comment: I have written an answer below, feel free to comment if you have any questions or if the answer is inaccurate!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need a valid JSON file, then you will be able to convert it to a JS object and work on it. In your data you have two keys, `11`, and `12`, I'm assuming you only need the first `11`'s value to construct the table.

The actual data you need to manipulate is contained inside an array. To work with arrays you can use build in methods from the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) class. Here I'm using [`Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), with `Boolean` as a callback (not a constructor), to remove any null values from the array.
Then I use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over each elements of the array.

I tried to figure out what you were going after. Based on your code, I managed do the following. Note the snippet is using a variable to store the stringified JSON. You can replace it with `$.JSON` and a callback to retrieve data from your file.

```js
const table = $('#content')

$(function() {
  const data = JSON.parse(json_string)["11"].filter(Boolean);
  
  data.forEach(function(el) {

    table.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Fajr: </td> <td> " + el.fajr_begins + " </td> <td> " + el.fajr_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

    table.append("<tr> <td> Sunrise: </td> <td> " + el.sunrise + " </td> <td> " + el.sunrise + " </td> </tr> ");

    table.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Ishraq: </td> <td> " + el.ishraq + " </td> <td> " + el.ishraq + " </td> </tr> ");

    table.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Zuhur: </td> <td> " + el.zuhr_begins + " </td> <td> " + el.zuhr_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

    table.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Asr: </td> <td> " + el.asr_mithl + " </td>  <td> " + el.asr_jamah + " </td>  </tr> ");

    table.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Magrib </td> <td> " + el.maghrib_begins + "</td> <td> " + el.maghrib_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

    table.append("<tr> <td> Salat Al-Isha </td> <td> " + el.isha_begins + " </td>  <td> " + el.isha_jamah + " </td> </tr> ");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Prayer </th>
      <th> Start </th>
      <th> Jamaat </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="content"></tbody>
</table>

<script>
  const json_string = '{"11":[null,{"asr_jamah":"","asr_mithl":"14:11","d_date":"1st","fajr_begins":"05:47","fajr_jamah":"","isha_begins":"","isha_jamah":"","maghrib_begins":"15:57","maghrib_jamah":"","sunrise":"07:51","zuhr_begins":"11:54","zuhr_jamah":""},{"asr_jamah":"","asr_mithl":"14:10","d_date":"2nd","fajr_begins":"05:49","fajr_jamah":"","isha_begins":"","isha_jamah":"","maghrib_begins":"15:57","maghrib_jamah":"","sunrise":"07:52","zuhr_begins":"11:55","zuhr_jamah":""},{"asr_jamah":"","asr_mithl":"14:10","d_date":"3rd","fajr_begins":"05:50","fajr_jamah":"","isha_begins":"","isha_jamah":"","maghrib_begins":"15:56","maghrib_jamah":"","sunrise":"07:53","zuhr_begins":"11:55","zuhr_jamah":""},{"asr_jamah":"","asr_mithl":"14:09","d_date":"4th","fajr_begins":"05:51","fajr_jamah":"","isha_begins":"","isha_jamah":"","maghrib_begins":"15:56","maghrib_jamah":"","sunrise":"07:55","zuhr_begins":"11:55","zuhr_jamah":""},{"asr_jamah":"","asr_mithl":"14:09","d_date":"5th","fajr_begins":"05:52","fajr_jamah":"","isha_begins":"","isha_jamah":"","maghrib_begins":"15:55","maghrib_jamah":"","sunrise":"07:56","zuhr_begins":"11:56","zuhr_jamah":""}],"12":[{"bmm_begins":0,"bmm_jamah":0},{"bmm_begins":"12:30 pm","bmm_jamah":"1:30 pm"},{"bmm_begins":"N/A","bmm_jamah":"N/A"},{"bmm_begins":"N/A","bmm_jamah":"N/A"},{"bmm_begins":"N/A","bmm_jamah":"N/A"}]}'
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this helps a lot . How i can point the data to a .json file ? also how I get the table to show the data based on time and date, I've added a link to paste bin (https://pastebin.com/B8xpFHnm) to show what i mean and js fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: By the way the json file is set as Month(11)/day(1) i thought i should only show last 2 months as it will be easier to understand

Answer (score -1):

Your variable dv must be initialized with 0 in order to performe the loop, and you can't add content to the closing  hmm